# Angular and Sinatra, templates loaded over ajax are not interpolated

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, sinatra

So, I'm trying to set up my first angular app and the problem is that the templates retrieved over ajax are not interpolated by the Angular.I am using Ruby Sinatra framework for the simple HTTP, and here are the main parts of the code:
index.html

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
})

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

});
```

home.html

```
{{ 1 + 1 }}
```

Sinatra app.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sinatra'

class HelloWorldApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    send_file 'index.html'
  end

  get '/js/:name' do
    send_file "js/#{params[:name]}"  
  end

  get '/templates/:name' do 
    send_file "templates/#{params[:name]}"
  end
end
```

Now, When I load `http://localhost:9292/` I get that `{{ 1 + 1 }}` instead of `2`.What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```